# Passing function input to name dimnames

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to assign names to list of dimnnames using inputs from an function, but the names only output the function input name (i.e. if `function(test1 = "abc)"` dimnames outputs "test1", not "abc"). An example function is here:

```
# example data
set.seed(123)
mcmr <- data.frame(type = rep(c("fm", "xp","mg"), each = 8),
                      teq = rep(c("string","ribbon"),  12),
                      value = sample(0:1, 24, replace = TRUE))

#example function
mcm_fun <- function(technique, test1, test2){
  test1 <- mcmr[mcmr$type == test1 & mcmr$teq == technique, "value"]
  test2 <- mcmr[mcmr$type == test2 & mcmr$teq == technique, "value"]
  matrix(c(table(test1), table(test2)), nrow = 2,
                dimnames = list(test1 = c("Positive", "Negative"), # want to name with test1 input
                                test2 = c("Positive", "Negative"))) # want to name with test2 input
}
```

Which outputs

```
mcm_fun("string", "mg", "xp")

#          test2
#test1      Positive Negative
#  Positive        1        3
#  Negative        3        1
```

The desired output would include the function input for `test1` and `test2`:

```
#          mg
#xp      Positive Negative
#  Positive        1        3
#  Negative        3        1
```

I have tried `assign()` and `get()` but cant seem to get this to work and all I can seem to find is info on assigning the dimnames themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels you're asking about are the `names` of the `dimnames` of the table, so you can set them with:

```
names(dimnames(m)) <- nms
```

In your case, just add that assignment step into your function:

```
mcm_fun <- function(technique, t1, t2){
    test1 <- mcmr[mcmr$type == t1 & mcmr$teq == technique, "value"]
    test2 <- mcmr[mcmr$type == t2 & mcmr$teq == technique, "value"]
    m <- matrix(c(table(test1), table(test2)), nrow = 2,
           dimnames = list(test1 = c("Positive", "Negative"), # want to name with test1 input
                           test2 = c("Positive", "Negative"))) # want to name with test2 input
    names(dimnames(m)) <- c(t1, t2)
    return(m)
}

mcm_fun("string", "mg", "xp")
          xp
mg         Positive Negative
  Positive        3        1
  Negative        1        3
```

Note that I had to rename your arguments since you were overwriting them with the results of the test.

Comment: Perfect, and thanks for changing the input names (product of a hastily made example function!).

Answer (score 1):

The `list` cannot evaluate the objects on the lhs of `=`, we can use `:=` with `lst` (from `dplyr` or `purrr`)

```
library(purrr)
mcm_fun <- function(technique, test1, test2){
  # assigned to a new object as the 
  # test1, test2 are assigned later to subset data
  nm1 <- test1
  nm2 <- test2
  test1 <- mcmr[mcmr$type == test1 & mcmr$teq == technique, "value"]
  test2 <- mcmr[mcmr$type == test2 & mcmr$teq == technique, "value"]
  matrix(c(table(test1), table(test2)), nrow = 2,
                dimnames = lst(!!nm1 := c("Positive", "Negative"), # want to name with test1 input
                                !!nm2 := c("Positive", "Negative"))) # want to name with test2 input

                            
}
```

-testing

```
> mcm_fun("string", "mg", "xp")
          xp
mg         Positive Negative
  Positive        3        1
  Negative        1        3
```